# Turning a tree into a heap in haskell

Tags: haskell, binary-tree, priority-queue

I need to make an implementation of a priority queue with a Heap Tree in Haskell, for example:

Given a list: `[3,2,7,8,4,1,9]`

```
3 is the  main root
2 is its left leaf
7 is its right leaf

8 is the left leaf of 2
4 is the right leaf of  2

1 is the left leaf of 7
9 is the right leaf of 7
```

If I want to heapifiy the tree it would be like this:

```
7 > 3 so we exchange them
8 > 2 we exchange them
8 > 7 we exchange them
9 > 3 we exchange them
9 > 8 we exchange them
```

We end with a list like this: `[9,7,8,2,4,1,3]`

And `9` is the element with the highest number (priority) in our queue.

I will need to do this:

- `insert h e` that inserts the element `e` in the heap `h` (in the last position)
- `delete h` that removes the element with the highest priority (in our example 9)
- `heapify h` that heapifies the tree.

But my problem is the heapify function, I dont even know where to start. That's why im asking for clues or advice.

Comment: What part is giving you trouble?

Comment: My problem is the heapify function, I dont even know where to start. That's why im asking for clues or advices

Comment: I've corrected my answer following Will Ness' comments. You should have a look.

Comment: in http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/aivika/latest/doc/html/Simulation-Aivika-PriorityQueue.html, "The 'PriorityQueue' type represents an imperative heap-based priority queue" with keys represented by `IORef (IOUArray Int Double)` and values by `IORef (IOArray Int a)`.

Comment: also, little Googling finds e.g. http://cs.brynmawr.edu/Courses/cs206/spring2012/slides/10_PriorityQueues.pdf which describes the algorithms that you ask about.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
module Heapify where
```

Let's use the tree type

```
data Tree a = Leaf a | Node (Tree a) a (Tree a) 
   deriving Show
```

and the example tree

```
ourTree = Node (Node (Leaf 8) 2 (Leaf 4))    3    (Node (Leaf 1) 7 (Leaf 9))
```

[image: tree]

And work out how to heapify it.

## Your description in pictures

### Top node

[image: do top node]

### Left subtree

[image: left subtree]

### Right subtree

[image: right subtree]

### Heapified?

In this case, the result is indeed a heap, but this method isn't the standard way of doing heapification, and doesn't generalise (as far as I can tell) to something that does make sure you have a heap. Credit to [Will Ness](https://stackoverflow.com/users/849891/will-ness) for pointing this out.

## How should we heapify?

A tree satisfies the heap property if each parent node is no smaller than its child nodes. (It says nothing about the compararive sizes of the child nodes.)

Heapification actually works a bit like insertion sort, in that you start at the low end, and work gradually up, dragging small elements back into place as you introduce them.

[image: heapify]

### Step 1:  Heapify the left and right subtrees

### Step 2: This node: Check if the top value should be pulled down

### Step 3: If so, heapify at that side again

Steps 1,2 and 4 are just recursive calls, so let's concentrate on the top node:

## Top node

We need to (a) see the value at the top of the subtrees and (b) be able to replace it.

[image: atTop]

```
atTop :: Tree a -> a
atTop (Leaf a) = a
atTop (Node _ a _) = a
```

[image: replaceTop]

```
replaceTop :: Ord a => Tree a -> a -> Tree a
replaceTop (Leaf _) a = Leaf a
replaceTop (Node l _ r) a = heapify (Node l a r)
```

Notice the cheeky forward reference to `heapify`? When we replace the top node of a tree, we need to re-heapify it to make sure it's still a tree.

Now let's see how to adjust at the left hand side if necessary.

[image: adjust left]

It's necessary if the top of the left subtree, `topL`, is larger than the value `a` at the node. If it's `<=` we don't need to do anything, so leave the node alone.

```
adjustLeft :: Ord a => Tree a -> Tree a
adjustLeft (Leaf a) = Leaf a   -- But we shouldn't ask to do this. 
adjustLeft  node@(Node l a r) 
     | topL <= a = node
     | otherwise = Node (replaceTop l a) topL r
         where topL = atTop l
```

and at the right:

[image: adjust right]

Now let's adjust at the right hand side if necessary. This works exactly the same.

```
adjustRight :: Ord a => Tree a -> Tree a
adjustRight (Leaf a) = Leaf a   -- But we shouldn't ask to do this. 
adjustRight  node@(Node l a r) 
     | topR <= a = node
     | otherwise = Node l topR (replaceTop r a) 
         where topR = atTop r
```

Let's see some of that working:

```
*Heapify> ourTree
Node (Node (Leaf 8) 2 (Leaf 4)) 3 (Node (Leaf 1) 7 (Leaf 9))
*Heapify> atTop ourTree
3
```

### Pull down to the Left or right?

If the current value belongs lower down the tree, we need to pull it down the left or the right side, by swapping it with the larger value of the two. We pick the larger value so we know it's more than the top value in the left subtree.

[image: do top node]

```
doTop :: Ord a => Tree a -> Tree a
doTop (Leaf a) = Leaf a
doTop node@(Node l a r) 
    | atTop l > atTop r = adjustLeft node
    | otherwise         = adjustRight node
```

Remember that `adjustLeft` and `adjustRight` make a recursive call to heapify.

### Return of the heapification

So to heapify, we just

```
heapify :: Ord a => Tree a -> Tree a
heapify (Leaf a) = Leaf a
heapify (Node l a r) = doTop (Node (heapify l) a (heapify r))
```

OK, that was easy. Let's test it:

```
*Heapify> ourTree
Node (Node (Leaf 8) 2 (Leaf 4)) 3 (Node (Leaf 1) 7 (Leaf 9))
*Heapify> heapify ourTree
Node (Node (Leaf 2) 8 (Leaf 4)) 9 (Node (Leaf 1) 7 (Leaf 3))
```

Comment: I cant tell you how much I appreciate your help.

Comment: @Pat SMART Notebook is a vector drawing package that comes free with any SMART Technologies interactive whiteboard.

Comment: sorry, but you've missed that this datatype can not host any even number of elements. and, `heapify` does not guarantee heap property after its operation: example: `[1,2,5]++[20,19..11]`. `node'` will have 5 at its top (`[5,20,18,...]`) and it would take more than just two swaps at top to heapify that tree.

Comment: @AndrewC I've attempted a review of your code at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/26565/9064 .  :)

Comment: Upvoting am old answer because this guy rocks. Well explained. I salute you! :)